# Writing persistent data in Android that stands even after flashing system image

Tags: android

I want to persist some data (just a register status) in Android even after user reflashes their device (change rom, etc.). Since it is just a small amount of data, I don't want to use a net server to save it. I do have root permission on the device.

Comment: Put the data on a server

Comment: as i said,it's just a register status and my app need to run under no network.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to persist some data (just a register status) in Android even after user reflashes their device (change rom, etc.).

There is no place that you can write on internal storage or external storage that will survive a factory reset/ROM replacement.

You are welcome to attempt to write something on removable storage, as this should not be affected by the factory reset, but removable storage is public, and other apps and the user can get rid of it entirely.